# Why am I getting a syntax error with this python ternary expression?

Tags: python, conditional-operator

Why am I getting a syntax error with this python ternary expression? Can't find anything in the documentation to say this is bad

`right_pointer -= 1 if condition else left_pointer += 1`

Comment: The ternary has nothing to do with it. `right_pointer -= left_pointer += 1` would be just as invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not a good way to code, but if you want a one-liner:**

```py
(right_pointer := right_pointer - 1) if condition else (left_pointer := left_pointer + 1)
```

This uses the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions), which is in Python 3.8+.

But using a normal if/else is recommended:

```py
if condition:
    right_pointer -= 1
else:
    left_pointer += 1
```

As Chepner says in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73210874), you can't use statements in the conditional expression, only expressions

Comment: I suspect this would have been made syntactically illegal if possible without complicating the grammar too much. :)

Comment: Thank you, @The Thonnu. My friends and I got bored doing leetcode so whoever can solve the most leetcode questions in one line gets a few bucks. I agree this is not safe for professional use

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing statements and expressions. The conditional expression has the form

```
<true-expression> if <condition> else <false-expression>
```

but you are trying to use it like a *statement* consisting of two "substatements":

```
<true-statement> if <condition> else <false-statement>
```

That is, Python tries to parse this as

```
right_pointer -= (1 if condition else left_pointer += 1)
```

not

```
(right_pointer -= 1) if condition else (left_pointer += 1)
```

There is no one-line conditional statement; you should simply use the regular `if` statement:

```
if condition:
    right_pointer -= 1
else:
    left_pointer += 1
```

---

The closest equivalent to what you are trying to write would be to use a conditional expression to select a bound method to call on `1`, something like

```
(right_pointer.__iadd__ if condition else left_pointer.__isub__)(1)
```

Even this is not quite identical, as `x += y` is formally equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`, not just `x.__iadd__(y)`.

(Update: I forgot about the legal, though not recommended, [use of `:=`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73210998/1126841). Don't actually use either of these.)

Comment: It could also be done using the walrus operator, but that's almost as gross as your last code.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how the walrus operator could be (ab)used here :).

Comment: See @TheThonnu's answer.

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot you could use `:=` even when the value isn't used later in the same expression/statement.